# iFrame won't become visible when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iFrame in HTML code, and I created a script tag that I set on a submit button. I want the iFrame to be visible when I click on the submit button, but that is not working. Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form.example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

form.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form.example button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}

form.example::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

#outerdiv
{
border:none;
width:100%;
height:500px;
overflow:hidden;

}

#innerIframe
{

border: none;
position:relative;
top:-190px;
width:100%;
height:900px;

}

</style>


</head>
<body>

<h2>Web Service</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showIFrame() {
var iframe = document.getElementById("innerIframe");
iframe.style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>

<form class="example" method="post"  style="margin:auto;max-width:500px">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search query" name="search2">
  <button type="submit" name="submit"  onclick="showIFrame()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>

<br>
<div id="outerdiv" >
<iframe src={{results}} id="innerIframe"  style="visibility: hidden;" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`{{results}}` is the URL that is passed by the user in python Flask. So in the form the user types in a word, which then joins it to a URL and performs a search. The search works perfectly, but when the page is loaded on startup, it shows `Not Found, the requested URL has not been found...` and I understand why that happens as the URL hasn't been loaded yet. So I want to make the iFrame invisible, and once the `submit` button is pressed, the frame can be visible.

I have tried with jQuery as well, but it did not work.

All help and advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Clicking this button will submit the form, and since it does not have an explicit action URL specified, this will result in re-loading the current URL. Of course any iframe you made visible on the _previous_ “page”, will not be visible any more after that. If you just want to show the iframe when that button is clicked, but not submit the form - then you either need to prevent the submit button default action in your event handling, or make it a different type of button to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First pass "event" when you call the onClick function in your HTML code like this *onclick="showIFrame(event)
2. Then in your function, you accept the "event" as a parameter like this *function showIFrame(event) {
3. A click button most times trigers your page to refresh, so you have to stop that by preventing the default action. Add "event.preventDefault()" to your function like this *event.preventDefault()

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input. But adding event.preventDefault() still does not make the iFrame visible for some reason. I added event.preventDefault() as the first line in my function. But it won't move to the next line and make the frame visible?

Comment: Did you do the first step, that is passing the "event" in your html code *onClick=showIFrame(event) cause I ran your code and it worked

Comment: I did do that, Yes. Thank you for your answer and suggestion. I shall try again, and hopefully it works.